# Cant link my pages in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a vertical drop down menu and the menu hides with Jquery, the problem is now that I can not link my pages with my menu in my li items my #href is not clickable, but the link is there.

Thanks in advance

http://68625.glr-imd.nl/motiongraphic.html# <---- url webpage

```
HTML:

 <a id="arrow" href="#"></a>

<div id="sidemenu" class="sidemenu">
    <img id="side_menu_img" src="styling/img/logo_no_letters.png" width="auto" height="40" style="margin-left:40px; margin-top:250px;">
    <ul id="side_menu" class="menu">
        <li style="margin-top:10px;"><a href="about.html">A b o u t</a>
        </li>
        <li style="margin-top:10px;"> <a id="portfolio" href="#">P o r t f o l i o</a>

            <ul>
                <li style="font-size:12px; margin-top:10px;"><a href="68625.glr-imd.nl/Websites.html">Web-Design</a>
                </li>
                <li style="font-size:12px;"><a href="Brandid.html">Brand Identity's </a>
                </li>
                <li style="font-size:12px;"><a href="projects.html">Projects</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li style="font-size:10px; margin-top:10px;"><a href="#">For the birds: The story continues</a>
                        </li>
                        <li style="font-size:10px;"><a href="#">Gia - The biography </a>
                        </li>
                        <li style="font-size:10px;"><a href="#">Glr Viral</a>
                        </li>
                        <li style="font-size:10px;"><a href="#">The Round Interface</a>
                        </li>
                        <li style="font-size:10px; margin-bottom:10px;"><a href="#">Shang Xia - Coming Soon</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li style="font-size:12px;"><a href="#">+&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Motion Graphic Design</a>
                </li>
                <li style="font-size:12px;"><a href="3dillu.html">3D Illustration</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li style="margin-top:10px;"> <a href="#">O f f - B o o k s</a> 
            <ul class="depth2">
                <li style="font-size:12px;"><a href="photography.html">Photography</a>
                </li>
                <li style="font-size:12px;"><a href="#">Drawings + Paintings</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <li style="margin-top:10px;"><a href="#">c o n t a c t</a>
            </li>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="iconbar">
        <img class="icon" src="styling/Icons/facebook.png">
        <img class="icon" src="styling/Icons/linkedin.png">
        <img class="icon" src="styling/Icons/tumblr.png">
        <img class="icon" src="styling/Icons/Youtube.png">
        <img class="icon" src="styling/Icons/meel.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .menu {
     width: 300px;
     height: 152px;
     padding: 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     margin-top: -76px;
     margin-left: 25px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
 }
 .menu li {
     margin:0;
 }
 .menu li {
     display:block;
     color:#000;
     overflow:hidden;
 }
 .menu li a {
     display:block;
     padding:5px;
     text-decoration:none;
     font-family:'quicksandlight';
     font-weight:900;
     color:#000;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     transition: all 0.5s ease;
     cursor:auto;
 }
 .menu li > ul {
     display:none;
     overflow:hidden;
     padding:10;
 }
 .menu p ul.depth2 li a {
     color:#fff;
     display:block;
 }
 .menu li a:hover {
     display:block;
     padding:5px;
     text-decoration:none;
     font-family:'quicksandlight';
     font-weight:900;
     color:#999;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     transition: all 0.5s ease;
 }
 .sidemenu {
     position:fixed;
     height:100%;
     left:0px;
     top:0;
     z-index:1500;
     width:375px;
     background-color:#FFF;
     margin-left:-375px;
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
     width: 0px;
 }
 #arrow {
     width:30px;
     height:100px;
     background-image:url(../img/arrow_l.png);
     position:fixed;
     left:0;
     top:50%;
     margin-top:-50px;
     z-index:2000;
     margin-left:0px;
     rotateZ:0;
 }
 @font-face {
     font-family:'quicksandlight';
     src: url('../fonts/quicksand-light-webfont.eot');
     src: url('../fonts/quicksand-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/quicksand-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/quicksand-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/quicksand-light-webfont.svg#quicksandlight') format('svg');
     font-weight:normal;
     font-style:normal;
 }
 .iconbar {
     height:32px;
     width:auto;
     position:absolute;
     top:100%;
     margin-top:-32px;
     left:25px;
 }
 .iconbar img {
     width:auto;
     height:16px;
     margin-right:15px;
     opacity:0.5;
 }
 .iconbar img:hover {
     opacity:1;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     transition: all 0.5s ease;
 }
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
    $("#portfolio").click(function() {
        if ($("#side_menu").css("margin-top") == "-76px") {
            $("#side_menu").animate({
                "margin-top": "-166px"
            }, 2500);
        } else {
            $("#side_menu").animate({
                "margin-top": "-76px"
            }, 500);
        }
    });
    $("#portfolio").click(function() {
        if ($("#side_menu_img").css("margin-top") == "250px") {
            $("#side_menu_img").animate({
                "margin-top": "160px"
            }, 2500);
        } else {
            $("#side_menu_img").animate({
                "margin-top": "250px"
            }, 500);
        }
    });


    $("#arrow").click(function() {
        if ($("#sidemenu").css("margin-left") == "0px") {
            $("#sidemenu").animate({
                "margin-left": "-375px"
            }, 500);
        } else {
            $("#sidemenu").animate({
                "margin-left": "-0px"
            }, 500);
        }
    });
    $("#arrow").click(function() {
        if ($("#arrow").css("margin-left") == "0px") {
            $("#arrow").animate({
                "margin-left": "335px"
            }, 500);
        } else {
            $("#arrow").animate({
                "margin-left": "-0px"
            }, 500);
        }
    });
    swfobject.registerObject("FLVPlayer");
</script>
```

Comment: I think it is working. How long is your page? Do you have scrollbars? The `<li>` items are just pointing to your `#` anchor tag which is at the top of the page (`<a id="arrow" href="#"></a>`) so they're just moving to the top of the page. If your page isn't long enough, you may not notice anything changing

Comment: You should really clean up your code and use CLASS and IDs instead of "style." Much easier to find your problem and for you to edit.

Comment: There is no problems with your links. [See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/439yc/). The only item that has an `href` that is a link is about. click the text "arrow", then click "about".

Comment: @jasonscript I dont have a problem with my menu it self but that I cant link them to my other pages. http://68625.glr-imd.nl/motiongraphic.html#

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The example you posted is very long, making it difficult for us to isolate the exact issue. Could you try trimming it down to a [short, self-contained, correct, compilable example](http://sscce.org/)? Be sure also to check the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to make sure we have the information needed to help you. Thanks!

Comment: To add on to Christian's comment, you should also provide a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code on your website, below code prevents you from clicking a link inside your menu:

```
$('.menu a').click(function( e ){
    //e.preventDefault(); // disable this to click enable the links
    $(this).parent('li').find('ul:first').slideToggle();
});
```

What you better do, is refine your selector `$('.menu a')` to a better one, in order to select the items that need to toggle a submenu. `about` and `contact` for example needs to remain an ordinary link if I have understood you correctly.

**HTML:**

```
<li>
    <a href="#" id="portfolio">P o r t f o l i o</a>
    <!-- optionally add a class or data-attribute here to properly select in jquery -->
    <!-- $('.menu ul') -->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Brandid.html">Brand Identity's</a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**JS:**

Find all the `a` elements prior to the `ul` elements inside `.menu`.
This should avoid selecting `about` and `contact` so they keep their default behavior to answer your question.

```
$('.menu ul').prev("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // continue
});
```

**some hints to clean up your code:**

On te jquery part, don't select the same items twice and don't bind it twice to the same event. Sounds like overkill, don't you think?

```
$("#portfolio").click() // 3 times
$("#arrow").click() // 2 times
```

On the css + jquery part, instead of animating `margin-top` you might want to try the height of the `.submenu` or switch to a [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function in jquery. Submenus are positioned `fixed` so it's better to avoid `margin` here and use `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` to adjust the position.

**example of improvement**

```
var mainmenu = $("#sidemenu"), // confuses with #side_menu so -> mainmenu
    arrow = $("#arrow");

arrow.click(function () {
    var mainmenuleft = parseInt(mainmenu.css("left"), 10),
        arrowleft = parseInt(arrow.css("margin-left"), 10);

    mainmenuleft = mainmenuleft === 0 ? -375 : 0; 
    arrowleft = arrowleft === 0 ? 335 : 0;

    mainmenu.animate({ left: mainmenuleft }, 500);
    arrow.animate({ marginLeft: arrowleft }, 500);
});
```

**FIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/tive/ez7WG/

Comment: thank u for your answer unfortunately I am not very good with JS. What do you mean with the selector and what would you change it to?

Comment: further to this answer, you do not need to use an empty <a> tag as your # anchor. Using href="#" will scroll to the top of the page by itself. It is also just as easy, and in my opinion better practice, to use the id of containers or headings instead of creating empty <a> tags.